How to implement shadcn UI button variant optional chaining typescript?
<Button variant = {${}}  size={"lg"} className={} text-lg } key={i}>{name}`
there are not working optional chaining.
error massage:
Type '${any}' is not assignable to type '"link" | "default" | "destructive" | "outline" | "secondary" | "ghost" | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
button.tsx(11, 7): The expected type comes from property 'variant' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps & RefAttributes'
I want to optional chaining any button type variant

You can directly add optional chaining like: variant={true ? "link" : "outline"}
